# Readline in vi mode: how can I enable up/down arrows?

Tags: vim, vi, readline

When bash has vi bindings available (set -o vi), up/down arrows work in both command and insertion mode.  When I setup readline's ~/.inputrc to use vi mode  (set editing-mode vi), applications like irb don't get the arrow functionality.   I've tried "set enable-keypad on" in inputrc to no effect.

How do I get bash-like arrow functionality in other readline aware applications?

Comment: Did you figure this out by any chance? :)

Comment: This seems like a bug just in Ruby 1.9's IRB Readline support, because the arrow keys work elsewhere (interactive Python shell, using rlwrap with SBCL, Ruby 1.8 IRB, etc)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue only with Ruby's readline (and it's still there).

I deal with it by skipping `set editing-mode vi` if we're using ruby's readline:

```
$if ruby
$else
  set editing-mode vi

  ...

$endif
```

There's not really anything else to do unless ruby's readline gets fixed.

Comment: If the mapping works in emacs mode, why not copy it across?

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only way I've been able to use the up/down arrow keys for history is to press ESC first.

This also works with the j and k keys, as long as ESC is pressed first.

Comment: I find _j_ & _k_ to be a **LOT** easier to type than the up/down arrows...